# UnboundStackError, referenced before assignment? Python

Tags: python

Here is some code im using in a larger program about bowling scoreboards, I have an almost identical snippet of code that works perfectly that declares the winner with the max, but I continue to get an error on this bit. It says that the "minname" in the print code is referenced before assignment but I can't for the life of me figure out whats up. FYI this is code in python.

```
print()
#Print a message to declare the loser (min)              
for i in range(total-1):
    if bowlerscorelist[i] < bowlerscorelist[i+1]:
        minscore = bowlerscorelist[i]
        minname = bowlernamelist[i]
print(minname, "got the lowest score with: ", minscore)
```

Any help?

Comment: Presumably, you don't have any items in the list where the condition is true.

Comment: It's impossible to say, the code you'e given us is not self-contained, so it will fail for reasons unrelated to the problem you are seeing, (e.g., it will give a `NameError` for `total`). But I *suspect* that you either never enter your for-loop, because `total-1 < 1`, *or* your `if` condition always fails, so `minname` is never assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entering the if statement (condition not met ofc), so "minscore" and "minname" are being referenced before assigment.

```
minname = ''
minscore = 0
 for i in range(total-1):
    if bowlerscorelist[i] < bowlerscorelist[i+1]:
        minscore = bowlerscorelist[i]
        minname = bowlernamelist[i]
print(minname, "got the lowest score with: ", minscore)
```